# Creating a user if they don't exist yet

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'd like to extend the following code:

```
create user someUser from login someLogin;
```

so that if I reexecute the script, I won't get errors telling me that the user already exists.

I've tried with the following.

```
select 
  case
  (
    select count(*) from sys.database_principals
    where name = 'someUser'
  )
    when 0 then 'create'
    else 'skip'
  end
```

But this only **selects** the strings. I'd like something to be executed instead. However, I get the error then telling me that there's something wrong near select and then. So the following doesn't fly and I'm not sure what to do about it.

```
case
(
  select count(*) from sys.database_principals
  where name = 'someUser'
)
  when 0 then (create user someUser from login someLogin)
end
```

EDIT:

The following code nags on me that the creation of the user must be the only command in the batch. I'm bluffed because it is the only one there. Also, How to circumvent the issue then?

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.database_principals where name = 'someUser')
  create user reader from login someLogin;
go
```

Comment: @user2246674 My bad. Lack of experience trouble-shooting SQL-issues. :)

Comment: What good would a *count* do you? It's either 0 or 1. Also `CASE` is an expression that returns a value; it is not for control of flow. Try `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE ...) CREATE USER someuser ...`

Comment: @AaronBertrand I saw a blog somewhere that recommended using *case* before *if*. I guess I misunderstood the point. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah would love to see that, do you remember the link? `CASE` does not make any sense whatsoever for control-of-flow. It's possible they used `CASE` in a query beforehand, then used the output for control of flow, but not directly. For example instead of just selecting the values, you could have said `SELECT @var = CASE ...` and then checked `@var` as part of control-of-flow.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yupp. It's [right here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/in-t-sql-use-casewhen-in-place-of-ifthen/5078041), so nobody thinks I'm BS-ing, haha.

Comment: That's actually recommending `CASE` for the opposite situation than the one you're using. You are trying to perform control-of-flow logic, which requires `IF/THEN` - and technically, you are ultimately performing DDL (creating a user), not a query in the traditional sense. A lot of people coming from other disciplines try to use control-of-flow logic in a query (using `IF/THEN`), but control-of-flow logic is not valid in a query like it is in a lot of language structures - you must test the result of expressions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ah, so trying to adopt to the the right way I actually went to far, haha. Thanks. Also, see my edit - I need help with your suggestion too.

Comment: Your edit adds a new construct I've never seen before - no expression can *start* with `CASE`. Again, `CASE` is not for control-of-flow (but is often mistaken as such because it does work that way in other languages). Did you try the code I posted in my first comment? `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'SomeUser') CREATE USER SomeUser FROM LOGIN SomeLogin;`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, that's in the edit. Maybe we missed each other or SO lagged. That's precisely the code I followed according to your advice. The error is that it's supposed to be the only statement in the batch.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it needs to be dynamic, `EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE USER...;';`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Dude, you're on fire tonight, in my eyes. Would you be good and put the conversation (edited of course) as a reply so I can check it green?

Comment: You can self-answer, I've got a daughter to feed then a hockey game to watch. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand What?! You mean that your child and hockey is more important than reputation on SO. Surely you're insane from all that SQL-ing... :)  (Seriously, though, I find it tacky to "steal" others answers, so I'd wait for a few days so you'll have time. Otherwise, I can perhaps summarize.)